# Checkbox change doesn't rerender but input text does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I got an issue regarding updating a child from a parent when checking/unchecking a checkbox.

When I type in the text input, my list is updated automatically following my research.
When I check the checkbox, it's supposed to rerender my  with only items where stocked=true. But it works only if I'm changing the content of the text input.

It's been two hours I'm trying to solve the issue, if someone can have a look and tell me...

Thanks by advance

```
const data = [
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football"},
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball"},
    {category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5"},
    {category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7"}
];

let dataFiltered = data;

let dataStock = data;

class Item extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    checkStock() {
        let styleStock = {};
        if(this.props.stocked === true) {
            
        } else {
            styleStock = {color: 'red'};
        }
        return styleStock;
    }

    render() {
        return <tr style={this.checkStock()}>
            <td>{this.props.children}</td>
            <td>{this.props.price}</td>
        </tr>;
    }

}

class Category extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getItems() {
        let items = [];
        let itemsN = 0;
        dataFiltered.forEach(dataF => {
            if(dataF.category === this.props.children) {
                itemsN++;
                items.push(<Item n={itemsN} price={dataF.price} stocked={dataF.stocked}>{dataF.name}</Item>);
            } else {

            }
        });
        return items;
    }

    render() {
        return <React.Fragment><tr><b>{this.props.children}</b></tr>{this.getItems()}</React.Fragment>;
    }

}

class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    getCategories() {
        let categoryCheck = [];
        let categoryList = [];
        let categoryN = 0;
        dataFiltered.forEach(dataF => {
            if(categoryCheck.includes(dataF.category)) {
                
            } else {
                categoryN++;
                categoryCheck.push(dataF.category);
                categoryList.push(<Category n={categoryN}>{dataF.category}</Category>);
            }
        });
        return categoryList;
    }

    render() {
        return <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
            </tr>
            {this.getCategories()}
        </table>
    }

}

class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {search: null, stock: false};
        this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this);
    }

    stockItem(value) {
        if(value === false) {
            dataStock = data;
        } else {
            dataStock = data.filter(dataF => dataF.stocked === true);
        }
    }

    searchItem(value) {
        const dataFilter = dataStock.filter(dataF => dataF.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()));
        dataFiltered = dataFilter;
    }

    handleSearch(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({search: value}, () => {
            this.searchItem(value);
            this.props.search(value);
        });
    }

    handleCheck(e) {
        const value = e.target.checked;
        if(value === true) {
            this.setState({stock: true}, () => {
                this.stockItem(value);
                this.props.stock(value);
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({stock: false}, () => {
                this.stockItem(value);
                this.props.stock(value);
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="searchBar" placeholder="Chercher un article" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.handleSearch} />
                <br />
                <input type="checkbox" id="stockCheck" name="stockCheck" value={this.state.stock} onChange={this.handleCheck} /><label htmlFor="stockCheck">Afficher uniquement les produits en stock</label>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }

}

class Full extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        this.stock = this.stock.bind(this);
    }

    search(value) {
        this.setState({search: value});
    }

    stock(value) {
        this.setState({stock: value});
    }

    render() { 
        return <div>
            <Form search={this.search} stock={this.stock} />
            <List search={this.search} stock={this.stock} />
        </div>;
    }

}

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div>
            <Full />
        </div>
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Instead of pasting the whole code, please make a minimal reproduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you handle state, don't use global variable. Read [managing state](https://react.dev/learn/managing-state).

It's 2023 please use `Functional Components`

```
stockItem(value) {
    if(value === false) {
        dataStock = data;
    } else {
        dataStock = data.filter(dataF => dataF.stocked === true);
    }
    // you're not updating "datafiltered"
    dataFiltered = dataStock
}
```

Comment: Well, that's what I did. Could you be a bit more precise regarding what I did wrong ?

Comment: State should be handled inside the components and not outside. And yes start using functional components there are many benefits to it, like hooks, you reduce the redundancies like in the `constructor`, `didComponentUpdate`...

Comment: And what is the purpose of `dataStock` anyways, you can remove it, unless you have a slightly different usage than your question.

Comment: Yes, I managed to make it work without this datastock shit, I used a condition instead while looping my items

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started React three days ago, I'm going to give a big look to it, thanks again

Comment: Just checkout `react` docs https://react.dev/learn and read through them they have example to show you how it works, I'm guessing you're following an old tutorial of sorts. And if the answer was helpful mark it as so